# Powershell looping through SharePoint Library to extract specific documents

Tags: powershell, sharepoint

I have modified a script I found online to loop through SharePoint Libraries and extract documents as a list. That all works fine and I get a html output file as nicely sorted and grouped per user and that is being emailed to me.

Now I need to modify this script further to be able to send emails to each user with only the users documents.
I made it so far that it creates separate files for each user and sends emails to the user with only the users documents BUT the first document is always missing in each users report. This means, when there is only one document from the user, the file created has no content.

See below code:

```
foreach($list in $alllistcol){

    if (($excludeLists -notcontains $list.Title) -and ($list.Basetype -eq "1"))
    {
        $files = GetListItems -site $site.Url -listname $list.Title

        # Loop through each file in the document library and perform the following
        #$files | Sort-Object -Property CreatedBy

        $lastAuthor = $file.ows_Author

        foreach($file in $files)
        {
            #Write-host "$($site.Title),$($list.Title),$($file.ows_LinkFileName)"
            #Write-Host "$($file.ows_LinkFileName)"

            # Use the following to add additional metadata columns

             if($lastAuthor -ne $file.ows_Author)
            {
                $AuthorFile = FileOutput
                SendEmail -outfile $AuthorFile -Author ($file.ows_Author -replace '[ ](?=[ ])|[^-_,A-Za-z ]+', '')
                $output = @()
                $lastAuthor = $file.ows_Author
            }else{   
                $record = new-object System.Object
                #$record | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name Site -value $site.Title
                #$record | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name List -value $list.Title
                #$record | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name FileTitle -value $file.ows_Title
                $record | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name Filename -value $file.ows_LinkFileName
                #$record | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name Created -value $file.ows_Created
                $record | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name CreatedBy -value ($file.ows_Author -replace '[ ](?=[ ])|[^-_,A-Za-z ]+', '')
                $record | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name ExpiryDate -value $file.ows_Expiry_x0020_Date
                #$record | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name Modified -value $file.ows_Modified
                #$record | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name ModifiedBy -value $file.ows_Editor
                #$record | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name ContentType -value $file.ows_ContentType
                #if ($file.ows_File_x0020_Size)
                #{
                #    $record | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name Filesize -value $file.ows_File_x0020_Size.split("([^#]+$)'")[-1]
                #}
                $output += $record
                $countfiles++

                #$output += "$($site.Title),$($list.Title),$($file.ows_Title),$($file.ows_LinkFileName),$($file.ows_Created)"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I think the problem is with the line: $lastAuthor = $file.ows_Author before actually declaring $file. How do I compare the author of a document to close and open a new file without skipping the first document for each author??

---------------------------------------------------------------Update------------------------------------------------------------

I have fixed the issue that the first document is skipped now.

```
if($lastAuthor -ne $file.ows_Author)
            {
                FileOutput
                SendEmail -Author ($file.ows_Author -replace '[ ](?=[ ])|[^-_,A-Za-z ]+', '')
                #$output = $null
                $output = @()
                #$lastAuthor = $null
                $lastAuthor = $file.ows_Author
                $record = new-object System.Object
                $record | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name Filename -value $file.ows_LinkFileName
                $record | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name CreatedBy -value ($file.ows_Author -replace '[ ](?=[ ])|[^-_,A-Za-z ]+', '')
                $record | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name ExpiryDate -value $file.ows_Expiry_x0020_Date
                $output += $record
                $countfiles++
            }else{   
                $record = new-object System.Object
                #$record | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name Site -value $site.Title
                #$record | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name List -value $list.Title
                #$record | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name FileTitle -value $file.ows_Title
                $record | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name Filename -value $file.ows_LinkFileName
                #$record | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name Created -value $file.ows_Created
                $record | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name CreatedBy -value ($file.ows_Author -replace '[ ](?=[ ])|[^-_,A-Za-z ]+', '')
                $record | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name ExpiryDate -value $file.ows_Expiry_x0020_Date
                #$record | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name Modified -value $file.ows_Modified
                #$record | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name ModifiedBy -value $file.ows_Editor
                #$record | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name ContentType -value $file.ows_ContentType
                #if ($file.ows_File_x0020_Size)
                #{
                #    $record | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name Filesize -value $file.ows_File_x0020_Size.split("([^#]+$)'")[-1]
                #}
                $output += $record
                $countfiles++

                #$output += "$($site.Title),$($list.Title),$($file.ows_Title),$($file.ows_LinkFileName),$($file.ows_Created)"
            }
```

Unfortunately I have found another issue: My query sorts by Author but somehow it does not loop through the last author. For example: I have 4 Authors - Amber, Mary, Sally and Wayne. Everything is fine with Amber, Mary and Sally. Their files are created properly and their emails are being send out correctly. Now Wayne's file has no content and his email of cause has no documents to show either. Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed issue myself :D

```
if (($excludeLists -notcontains $list.Title) -and ($list.Basetype -eq "1"))
    {
        $files = GetListItems -site $site.Url -listname $list.Title

        # Loop through each file in the document library and perform the following
        #$files | Sort-Object -Property CreatedBy

        $lastAuthor = $null

        foreach($file in $files)
        {
            #Write-host "$($site.Title),$($list.Title),$($file.ows_LinkFileName)"
            #Write-Host "$($file.ows_LinkFileName)"

            # Use the following to add additional metadata columns

            if($lastAuthor -eq $null)
            {
                $lastAuthor = $file.ows_Author
            }

            if($lastAuthor -ne $file.ows_Author)
            {
                FileOutput
                SendEmail -Author ($lastAuthor -replace '[ ](?=[ ])|[^-_,A-Za-z ]+', '')
                #$output = $null
                $output = @()
                #$lastAuthor = $null
                $lastAuthor = $file.ows_Author
            }
            $record = new-object System.Object
            #$record | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name Site -value $site.Title
            #$record | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name List -value $list.Title
            #$record | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name FileTitle -value $file.ows_Title
            $record | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name Filename -value $file.ows_LinkFileName
            #$record | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name Created -value $file.ows_Created
            $record | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name CreatedBy -value ($file.ows_Author -replace '[ ](?=[ ])|[^-_,A-Za-z ]+', '')
            $record | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name ExpiryDate -value $file.ows_Expiry_x0020_Date
            #$record | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name Modified -value $file.ows_Modified
            #$record | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name ModifiedBy -value $file.ows_Editor
            #$record | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name ContentType -value $file.ows_ContentType
            #if ($file.ows_File_x0020_Size)
            #{
            #    $record | Add-Member -type NoteProperty -name Filesize -value $file.ows_File_x0020_Size.split("([^#]+$)'")[-1]
            #}
            $output += $record
            $countfiles++

            #$output += "$($site.Title),$($list.Title),$($file.ows_Title),$($file.ows_LinkFileName),$($file.ows_Created)"

            if($files.IndexOf($file) -eq ($files.Count -1))
            {
                FileOutput
                SendEmail -Author ($lastAuthor -replace '[ ](?=[ ])|[^-_,A-Za-z ]+', '')
            }
        }
    }
```

The last if is checking if the file is the last in the foreach iteration and creates the file and send email to the last Author.